# pyramid sequence in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java. Just now I'm practing. If I give input as 6, output should be like this:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

Here I'm posting code that I tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Number {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        in.close();
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        {
            // k=i;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + k);
                if (n==k)
                {
                    break;
                }
                k++;
            }       
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

If I input n=4,i t show the output as:

```
1

2 3

4

4
```

Comment: Idenation meka your code readable. This is the minimum to do when asking for help (and it will eventually make the solution of your problem obvious).

Answer (score 2):

Your `break` will only exit the inner loop (the one that loops over `j`). The outer loop will continue to run, leading to extra numbers being printed.

You need to *either* replace it with a `return;` or `System.exit(0)`, *or* put a label in front of your outer loop (the one that loops over `i`) and use a [labeled break](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Comment: `return` is probably the best option.

Comment: I agree. Especially when the "print a number pyramid for `n`" code is extracted to a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

Properly indent your code. It helps your brain to understand.

That said, the solution is two loops with three variables.

You need a loop that goes from 1 to n.

An inner loop that goes from 1 to the number of elements per line.

And you need the number of elements per line. This variable increases every time the inner loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a badly worded question, but I'm going to guess you want to know why the extra 4?

The reason is you have nested loops, so the `break` only breaks one loop. Here's how you break out of the outer loop:

```
outer: for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
...
break outer;
```

The label `outer` is arbitrary - you can call it `fred` is you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 6; // target

int i = 0;
int nextRowAt = 2;
int currentRow = 1;
while (++i <= n) {
    if (i == nextRowAt) {
        System.out.println();
        nextRowAt = ++currentRow + i;
    }
    System.out.print("" + i + " ");
}
```

But unless you understand it and can properly explain the code, you will probably get a fail on your assignment.

My suggestion is to start by creating/understanding on pen and paper. Write out the sequences and figure out how the algorithm should work. THEN you start coding it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum =0;
int n =10;
//        n------> number till where you want to print
boolean limtCrossed = false;
for (int i = 0; i < n &&!limtCrossed; i++) {
 for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
  sum++;
  if (sum>n) {
    limtCrossed = true;
    break;
  }
  System.out.print(+ sum +" " );
 }

 System.out.println("\n");

}
```

Comment: COuld you please highlight the main aspect(s) of your answer and how it solves the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n = 10;
    int k = 1;
    boolean breakOuter = false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" " + k);
        if (n==k)
        {
        breakOuter = true;
        break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if(breakOuter) break;
    System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's ... un-elegant. I'm not a huge fan of labeled breaks, but it would be much nicer here.

Comment: Labeled breaks feels kinda Basic, in all senses of the word :)